# Finding the max and min in a tuple of tuples

Tags: python, tuples, normalization

I'm new to python and having some problems finding the minimum and maximum values for a tuple of tuples. I need them to normalise my data. So, basically, I have a list that is a row of 13 numbers, each representing something. Each number makes a column in a list, and I need the `max` and `min` for each column. I tried indexing/iterating through but keep getting an error of

```
max_j = max(j)

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

any help would be appreciated!

The code is (assuming data_set_tup is a tuple of tuples, eg ((1,3,4,5,6,7,...),(5,6,7,3,6,73,2...)...(3,4,5,6,3,2,2...)) I also want to make a new list using the normalised values.

```
normal_list = []

for i in data_set_tup:

    for j in i[1:]: # first column doesn't need to be normalised
        max_j = max(j)
        min_j = min(j)
        normal_j = (j-min_j)/(max_j-min_j)
        normal_list.append(normal_j)
    normal_tup = tuple(normal_list)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can transpose rows to columns and vice versa with `zip(*...)`. (Use `list(zip(*...))` in Python 3)

```
cols = zip(*data_set_tup)
normal_cols = [cols[0]] # first column doesn't need to be normalised
for j in cols[1:]:
    max_j = max(j)
    min_j = min(j)
    normal_cols.append(tuple((k-min_j)/(max_j-min_j) for k in j)

normal_list = zip(*normal_cols)
```

Comment: This still gives me max and min for each row, whereas I need the max an min for each column (each tuple is a row, with the values inside it making up the columns, like a matrix). Any suggestions for getting the max and min of a column?

Answer (score 0):

This really sounds like a job for the non-builtin [numpy](https://numpy.org/) module, or maybe the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) module, depending on your needs.

Adding an extra dependency on your application should not be done lightly, but if you do a lot of work on matrix-like data, then your code will likely be both faster and more readable if you use one of the above modules throughout your application.

I do not recommend converting a list of lists to a numpy array and back again just to get this single result -- it's better to use the pure python method of Jannes answer. Also, seeing that you're a python beginner, numpy may be overkill right now. But I think your question deserves an answer pointing out that this *is* an option.

Here's a step-by-step console illustration of how this would work in numpy:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1,3,4,5,6],[5,6,7,3,6],[3,4,5,6,3]], dtype=float)
>>> a
array([[ 1.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.],
       [ 5.,  6.,  7.,  3.,  6.],
       [ 3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  3.]])
>>> min = np.min(a, axis=0)
>>> min
array([1, 3, 4, 3, 3])
>>> max = np.max(a, axis=0)
>>> max
array([5, 6, 7, 6, 6])
>>> normalized = (a - min) / (max - min) 
>>> normalized
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.66666667,  1.        ],
       [ 1.        ,  1.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.5       ,  0.33333333,  0.33333333,  1.        ,  0.        ]])
```

So in actual code:

```
import numpy as np

def normalize_by_column(a):
    min = np.min(a, axis=0)
    max = np.max(a, axis=0)
    return (a - min) / (max - min)
```

Answer (score 0):

We have `nested_tuple = ((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9))`.
First of all we need to normalize it. Pythonic way:

```
flat_tuple = [x for row in nested_tuple for x in row]
```

Output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] `# it's a list`

Move it to tuple: `tuple(flat_tuple)`, get max value: `max(flat_tuple)`, get min value: `min(flat_tuple)`